# Optimization allocation problem using logs

Tags: calculus

The country is fighting two wars at the same time. A general has to decide how to allocate M troops. With the most recent analysis of the situations, he knows that the benefit of placing "a" troops on front A is 10 In(a) and the benefit for placing "b" troops on front B is 20 In(b).  What is the optimal fraction of troops he can best place on both fronts.

I started with M= 10 In(a)-(-20 In(b)) and ended up with a/2b, which is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You need to maximize the benefit, so you need to maximize $f(a,b)=10\ln(a)+20\ln(b)$. Since you're given a fixed number $M$ of troops, you have $a+b=M$. Hence $$g(a)=f(a,M-a)=10\ln(a)+20\ln(M-a)$$ is what you need to maximize. Apply the standard methods you've hopefully learned.

Answer (score 1):

With $f_a M= a $ and $(1-f_a)M=b$ benefit $B$ is $$B=10\ln(f_a M) +20\ln((1-f_a)M). $$
The derivation of $B$ by $f_a$,
$$ \dfrac{dB}{df_a} = 0,$$
yields an equation for an optimal $f_a$. The value is $f_a = 1/3$, which is the fraction of available troops M to send to A.

Answer (score 0):

(M)max = 10 ln(a) + 20 ln(b)

= 10 ln(a) + 20 ln(M-a)        see M=a+b t.f. M-a=b

M' =10/a + -20/(M-a) = 0

10/a = 20/(M-a)              cross multiply

10M - 10a = 20a

30M = 30a

a = (1/3)M

thus,

optimal a = 1/3*M

No where near as eloquent, possibly just luck, but I got it right.